# Spring Boot/MVC: Consider defining a bean of type 'pack.website.repositories.CustomerRepository' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

before I explain the problem, I have gone through similar threads that result in the error I am facing. So I have looked and none of the solutions have been helpful, therefore, I am posting my own custom question. Creating a simple Spring Boot/MVC project I am getting this error:

> Description:
>
> Field cRepo in pack.website.controllers.LandingPageController required
> a bean of type 'pack.website.repositories.CustomerRepository' that
> could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'pack.website.repositories.CustomerRepository' in your configuration.

after configuring my Controller class, and repo class. Below I will attach the codes and my main. Does anyone know why this error is still occurring? I've tried @component, @service (in my service class), @repository tag.... Still does not work. Please help:

```
@Controller
public class LandingPageController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository cRepo;

    @GetMapping("")
    public String viewLandingPage() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
        return "signup_form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/process_register")
    public String processRegister(Customer customer) {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(customer.getPassword());
        customer.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        cRepo.save(customer);

        return "register_success";
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String listUsers(Model model) {
        List<Customer> listUsers = cRepo.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("listUsers", listUsers);

        return "users";
    }

}
```

#############

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>{
    
    public Customer findByEmail(String email);

}
```

#############

```
public class CustomerService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository cRepo;

    @Override
    public CustomerDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Customer customer = cRepo.findByEmail(username);
        if (customer == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        return new CustomerDetails(customer);
    }

}
```

###########

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"pack.website.controllers", "pack.website.repositories" })
public class ProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add "@Repository" before the declaration of "CustomerRepository" and try again?

Comment: @AndresSacco I have tried that too.

Comment: Look the packages that you scan in the "ProjectApplication". You only scan the controllers and repositories but not the services, try to scan "pack.website" and add Service tag in "CustomerService" . Also add "repository" tag in CustomerRepository

Comment: @AndresSacco I gave that a go. Same error. Now, when I add @ComponentScan({"pack.website.controllers.LandingPageController", "pack.website.repositories.CustomerRepository" }) to my main. It builds, but spring security's default login shows instead of my custom Index.html. and I've tried disabling spring security.... but that didnt work.

Comment: Try to remove the componentScan annotation and add the paths to be scanned in the following annotation: @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"pack.website"}), of course do not forget to decorate your repository with the annotation @Repository.

Comment: @JuanBC Just gave that a try... same error. Now, when I remove my componentscan and just keep springbootapplication the project builds but displays the default spring login screen and not mine, and then when I use ur suggestions and also add the pack.website.controllers in the scanbasepackages it throws same error of bean again.

Comment: can you copy at least the line that contains "package" at the beginning of your repository class ?? maybe there is a typo...

Comment: @JuanBC what do u mean? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: If you go the file CustomerRepository.java, You will see that it starts with the word "package" and then something, can you copy that line and post it??

Comment: @JuanBC yes, its: package pack.website.repositories;

Answer (score 1):

With Service Layer @Service annotation may help following is controller part

```
package com.example.jpalearner.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.jpalearner.jpa.JpaService;
import com.example.jpalearner.jpa.Studentinformation;
import com.example.jpalearner.service.StudentInfoService;
@RestController
public class RouterController {
    
    @Autowired
    StudentInfoService service;
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/searchByservice")
    public Studentinformation  searchByservice(@RequestBody Studentinformation studentinformation)
    {
        try {
            return service.fetchByName(studentinformation);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        return null;

    }
    
}
```

Service Interface

```
package com.example.jpalearner.service;

import com.example.jpalearner.jpa.Studentinformation;

public interface StudentInfoService {
    public Studentinformation fetchByName(Studentinformation obj);
}
```

And the implementation

```
package com.example.jpalearner.service.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.jpalearner.jpa.JpaService;
import com.example.jpalearner.jpa.Studentinformation;
import com.example.jpalearner.service.StudentInfoService;
@Service
public class StudentInfoServiceImpl implements StudentInfoService {
    @Autowired
    private JpaService repos;
    @Override
    public Studentinformation fetchByName(Studentinformation obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return repos.findByStudentname(obj.getStudentname());
    }

}
```

[image]

If i miss @Service annotation then following error will occur

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be its not able to scan the package properly or you are missing @service tag in CustomerService.java , while check wether following code is usefull folowing is the ServletInitializer

```
package com.example.jpalearner;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.jpalearner" })
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ServletInitializer.class);
    }

}
```

followed by RouterController

```
package com.example.jpalearner.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.jpalearner.jpa.JpaService;
import com.example.jpalearner.jpa.Studentinformation;
@RestController
public class RouterController {
    @Autowired
    private JpaService repos;
    
    
    @GetMapping
    public String defaultpath()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
    
    @PutMapping(value = "/save")
    public Map<String, Object> SaveRecord(@RequestBody Studentinformation studentinformation) {
        Map<String, Object> res = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        try {
            repos.save(studentinformation);
            res.put("saved", true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            res.put("Error", e);
        }
        return res;

    }
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/search")
    public Studentinformation  GetRecord(@RequestBody Studentinformation studentinformation)
    {
        try {
            return repos.findByStudentname(studentinformation.getStudentname());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Interface to implement JPA

```
package com.example.jpalearner;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface JpaService extends CrudRepository<Studentinformation, Long> {

    public Studentinformation findByStudentname(String email);
}
```

which uses entity class

```
package com.example.jpalearner.jpa;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Studentinformation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long regid;
    
    public Long getRegid() {
        return regid;
    }

    public void setRegid(Long regid) {
        this.regid = regid;
    }
    
    private String studentname;

    public String getStudentname() {
        return studentname;
    }

    public void setStudentname(String studentname) {
        this.studentname = studentname;
    }


}
```

application properties as following

```
## default connection pool
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5

## PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testjpa
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=xyz@123
```

Following is the pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.jpalearner</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplejpalearner</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>simplejpasample</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot, and jpa test</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have not used @Service or @Repository tags(as repo is autowired in controller) , while i have just added base package name, hope it helps @throwawayaccount2020 while if you use an interface to work on Repository then @Service tag is required

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.jpalearner" })
```

Sql

```
CREATE TABLE studentinformation
(
  regid serial NOT NULL,
  studentname character varying(250) NOT NULL
);
```

Filetree

[image: following]